# Reject this edit

Tags: discussion

I was reviewing [this edit](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/48355) and I found it to be 'racist'.

1. It excludes Israel from the list of countries
2. The etymology of the word [Laban](http://www.behindthename.com/name/laban) comes from Hebrew

Posted here, just in case the other reviewers let this slip.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like folks already rejected it, and it was proposed by an anonymous user, so nothing else to do.

Comment: Ah, yes, Jolenealaska